# Definition of Completion

Tags: metric-spaces

I am learning metric spaces on my own. Recently, I am studying completion of metric space.

I have found this definition.

[image]

Is the definition correct? Should not $Y$ be a complete metric space?

Comment: @drhab Are you saying that $Y$ can be a completion of $X$ even if $Y$ itself is not complete? I don't think so.

Comment: It should say "*A complete metric space $(Y,d_Y)$*...". So, $Y$ has to be complete by definition, and a-priori, one shouldn't use the same symbol $d$ twice.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was wrong (and of course deleted). Thank you for attending me. [This](http://sites.iiserpune.ac.in/~supriya/teaching/Topology-MTH322/files/Completion.pdf) made me wiser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES. $(Y, d') $ should be a complete metric space .

Otherwise $Id: X\to X$ is an onto isomerty .

Thus $X$ is completion of itself. But $(X, d) $ need not complete here. So $(Y, d') $ must be a complete metric space.